# What is the behavior of redirects when there's no command?

Tags: bash

If I run

```
$(</dev/stdin)
```

Then type `echo hello world`, press enter, then `Ctrl-D`

We get

`hello world`

But why? When I think of I/O and redirection in bash, it only makes sense to me when there's an actual command. I don't understand the behavior when there's no command, and it's just `< my_file`

Could someone help explain/point me to a primary source that explains this further? Thanks!

Comment: For a primary source, see [Bash reference manual 3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution): "The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`."

Comment: thanks for the info, @muru!